# Android autocomplete multiple textview lines in one result

Tags: android, autocomplete, textview, android-arrayadapter

is there anyway to have two TextView in one AutoCompleteTextView result?

e.g.

```
-------------------------------
result 1 title
result 1 alt text
-------------------------------
result 2 title
result 2 alt text
-------------------------------
```

And so on...

The ArrayAdapter only allows one binding for a view so how could I bind more views in the adapter?

Like so:

```
(...= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_1item, R.id.list_item, String[]);
```

I've created a new xml layout for the layout parameter in the ArrayAdapter except when I bind the TextView to the string array, it only sets the text to the TextView with the given id.

I've also searched through the other posts about this one and it did not suit my needs.

If anyone could help that would be absolutely great :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can 'extend' the ArrayAdapter class with your own implementation. After extending the ArrayAdapter, use a LayoutInflater to load an XML layout. You can then override the getView method in order to populate the layout's UI fields.

[Here is an example of how you could do it](http://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/)

I would advise to inflate the layout in the ArrayAdapter's constructor though, it avoids some of the unnecessary if statements you see in the author's code samples.